# Rails system test screenshot spam in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, capybara

This is my first question on Stack overflow so you may have to bear with me!

I am running some system tests in my application, and whenever a test fails it takes a screenshot but also seems to paste some kind of encoded filename with it too, eg:

https://pastebin.com/eHKVUVui (too long to paste so please see link)

`[Screenshot]: tmp/screenshots/failures_test_Admin_permissions.png
]1337;File=name=ZmFpbHVyZXNfdGVzdF9BZG1pbl9wZXJtaXNzaW9ucy5wbmc=;height=400px;inline=1:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABW4AAAM6CAYAAAAR+9rFAAAgAElEQVR4nOzde3zT5d3/8VfapoXQktIGaDi0YAEr0E2CWuQujDook+KGOtRxT3E/1N243aDzMJzKdqO7xdNU3OzthM2qQ5E5mROmBVfFilQlqOVQ6ao2HMIhLYSW0DZt8/ujFJombdO0QNX38/HYY3p9872+Vw6F+s7n+7kMtbW1PkRERERERERERESkW9XU1IR9bkQ3rkNEREREREREREREuoGCWxEREREREREREZEeRsGtiIiIiIiIiIiISA+j4FZERERERERERESkh1FwKyIiIiIiIiIiItLDKLgVEREREREREREROcNee+21do8ruBURERERERERERE5g5pD2/bCWwW3IiIiIiIiIiIiImdI67C2rfBWwa2IiIiIiIiIiIjIGdBWSBts`...

etc

I would like to stop this spam in my terminal but continue to have it take screenshots for me, is there a way to do this?

Comment: That is not an encoded filename, it is an object. `LoginTest` is the class, and `0x0000000662c900` is the object id. And why do you want to get rid of the test output? It tells you what the error is, as well as a potential fix for the test failure.

Comment: I mean the bit indicating a screenshot has been taken, not the test result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're seeing is Rails attempting to display the actual screenshot in the terminal.  It appears your terminal is not capable/configured to display an image.  This behavior is controllable through a couple of environment variables - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb#L58

By setting one of those environment variables to 'simple' you can prevent Rails from outputting the image to the terminal, something along the lines of

```
RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT=simple bundle exec rspec
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! I found the API page http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/SystemTesting/TestHelpers/ScreenshotHelper.html and added `ENV['RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT'] = 'simple'` to my application_system_test_case.rb file and has worked

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the terminal output with

```
Capybara::Screenshot::RSpec.add_link_to_screenshot_for_failed_examples = false
```

Comment: This is only valid if the user is using the `capybara-screenshot` gem and controls whether or not a link to the failed screenshot is added to the output - not whether or not the entire image is dumped to the terminal.